# Pass scope in node between different files/scripts

Tags: node.js, scope, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to unit test some of the Kue (redis) functions of my node server. Of course Mocha starts its own process. This process has its own instance which is, of course, scope protected from the node server I have running on the same physical server (my laptop in this case as I am in dev env).

My question is: how can the mocha server check any variables or events from the main node server? I realize I could get tricky and have node push variables to redis and then poll redis from mocha but that seems arduous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Since the mocha is launching in a separate node process, any javascript variables global or local are relatively scoped to that individual node process.  You are correct with the redis suggestion to send a message from process to process or literally launch the node server inside your mocha framework.